# Virtual inheritance and static inheritance - mixing in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

If you have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class A
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        T::func();
    }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    virtual void func()
    {
        std::cout << "into func";
    }
};

class C : public B
{
};

int main()
{
  C c;
  c.func();

  return 0;
}
```

Is func() dynamically dispatched?
How could you implement class A such that if B has a virtual override, that it is dynamically dispatched, but statically dispatched if B doesn't?

Edit: My code didn't compile? Sorry guys. I'm kinda ill right now. My new code also doesn't compile, but that's part of the question. Also, this question is for me, not the faq.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class A
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        T::func();
    }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    virtual void func()
    {
        std::cout << "in B::func()\n";
    }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual void func() {
        std::cout << "in C::func()\n";
    }
};
class D : public A<D> {
    void func() {
        std::cout << "in D::func()\n";
    }
};
class E : public D {
    void func() {
        std::cout << "in E::func()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
  C c;
  c.func();
  A<B>& ref = c;
  ref.func(); // Invokes dynamic lookup, as B declared itself virtual
  A<D>* ptr = new E;
  ptr->func(); // Calls D::func statically as D did not declare itself virtual
  std::cin.get();

  return 0;
}

visual studio 2010\projects\temp\temp\main.cpp(8): error C2352: 'B::func' : illegal call of non-static member function
      visual studio 2010\projects\temp\temp\main.cpp(15) : see declaration of 'B::func'
      visual studio 2010\projects\temp\temp\main.cpp(7) : while compiling class template member function 'void A<T>::func(void)'
      with
      [
          T=B
      ]
      visual studio 2010\projects\temp\temp\main.cpp(13) : see reference to class template instantiation 'A<T>' being compiled
      with
      [
          T=B
      ]
```

Comment: Added to the FAQ, seemed useful.

Comment: Maybe by stating what you intend to do will give you a far better solution, and by saying "better" I mainly mean maintainable, where you could read and **understand** your own code later on.

Comment: @the_drow: This question needs a lot of help before it becomes a FAQ candidate.  The code example needs to be changed so that it compiles, then the poster needs to explain how the actual behavior is different from the desired behavior, then it can be answered and, if it seems general enough, faq-ified.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: It seems that this question is very useful for those who want to learn about the v-talbe and how does c++ it's magic under the hoods. What can be done to improve this message?

Comment: @the_drow: This question has nothing to do with the internals of virtual function implementation.  I think it has something to do with the interaction between template specialization, compile-time overload resolution, and dynamic dispatch via virtual functions, but it's hard to answer questions about the behavior of code that can't compile.

Comment: @DeadMG: I think you want `static_cast<T*>(this)->func();` which has the benefit that it actually will compile (once the accessibility is fixed), and when `T::func` is declared virtual, be polymorphic.  Note that since it's inlined, it may only be dynamic dispatch when the call site doesn't have exact type information.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: The code currently compiles just fine. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @the_drow: Does it compile fine with `std::count << "info func"`?  See http://ideone.com/Vkoi7 for the real issue.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Yes and on the other hand: http://codepad.org/fhbLcRQr

Comment: @the_drow: That never instantiates A<T>::func.  Are you saying the goal is to never call A<T>::func?

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Ok so now I get the problem. :)

Comment: @Fred Nurk: The static cast Ben suggested indeed solves this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but it appears you are missing the essential CRTP cast:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
  void func() {
    T& self = *static_cast<T*>(this);  // CRTP cast
    self.func();
  }
};

struct V : A<V> {  // B for the case of virtual func
  virtual void func() {
    std::cout << "V::func\n";
  }
};

struct NV : A<NV> {  // B for the case of non-virtual func
  void func() {
    std::cout << "NV::func\n";
  }
};
```

If T does not declare its own func, this will be infinite recursion as self.func will find A<T>::func.  This is true even if a derived class of T (e.g. DV below) declares its own func but T does not.

Test with different final overrider to show dispatch works as advertised:

```
struct DV : V {
  virtual void func() {
    std::cout << "DV::func\n";
  }
};
struct DNV : NV {
  void func() {
    std::cout << "DNV::func\n";
  }
};

template<class B>
void call(A<B>& a) {
  a.func();  // always calls A<T>::func
}

int main() {
  DV dv;
  call(dv);   // uses virtual dispatch, finds DV::func
  DNV dnv;
  call(dnv);  // no virtual dispatch, finds NV::func

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I could've written out DV and DNV explicitly, and perhaps I should've for clarity, but note that D<V>::func is virtual implicitly because its inherited V::func is virtual.

Comment: How is this an improvement over simply not making `func` virtual?  You can't invoke `call()` with any kind of pointer to a supertype (in fact in the example there is no supertype).

Comment: @Ben: In the OP's code, there is no common base type ("supertype") either. This is a minimal reformulation of the OP's code that, as far as I can tell, does what he asks (the CRTP comment and next line are the key), then shows that with a short example.

Comment: I had considered the use of static_cast. However, I'm more than a bit apprehensive about casting, as it may mask errors (e.g., `class C : public A<B>` which would otherwise fail, and secondly, I'm concerned about it losing CV and rvalue/lvalue qualifiers.

Comment: @DeadMG: C++0x's static_assert that A is a base class of T (or the non-0x equivalent) solves the first, but that's just how CRTP works and isn't generally a problem in practice.  static_cast *can't* remove CV qualifiers; trying will yield a compile error.  `*this` is always an lvalue within a method, as is my *self* above.

Comment: @DeadMG: Comparing my example to your updated code in the question: your B corresponds to my V, similarly for C => DV, D => NV, and E => DNV.  I used a function instead of local A refs (and ref vs pointer doesn't matter here).  Otherwise our code is equivalent, except A::func is corrected here.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: `*this` is not always an lvalue in C++0x, it may be an rvalue. I don't have a compiler that supports rvalue *this, but I sure want my code to work when I do.

Comment: @DeadMG: I was talking in the context of current C++, only earlier mentioning 0x to clarify static_assert.  However, `*this` is still an lvalue in 0x, but the method can only be called on rvalues if the method has that ref-specifier.  Compare to x in void f(int&& x); the value supplied for x must be an rvalue, but inside f, x is an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

> How could you implement class A such that if B has a virtual override, that it is dynamically dispatched, but statically dispatched if B doesn't?

Somewhat contradictory, isn't it?  A user of class A may know nothing about B or C.  If you have a reference to an A, the only way to know if `func()` needs dynamic dispatch is to consult the vtable.  Since `A::func()` is not virtual there is no entry for it and thus nowhere to put the information.  Once you make it virtual you're consulting the vtable and it's dynamic dispatch.

The only way to get direct function calls (or inlines) would be with non-virtual functions and no indirection through base class pointers.

Edit:  I think the idiom for this in Scala would be `class C: public B, public A<C>` (repeating the trait with the child class) but this does not work in C++ because it makes the members of `A<T>` ambiguous in `C`.

Comment: Actually, using CRTP does let you know about B within A (that's the whole point of CRTP).

Comment: I may be confused by the question.  As written, `func` is private so `C.func()` is a compile error.  `B::func()` hides the inherited `A<B>::func()` entirely (as written) so the only possible caller of `A<B>::func()` is `A<B>`, so yes, it knows about `B` but it can't know about `C`.  So perhaps my first sentence should be "A<B> knows nothing about (any possible) C"

Comment: You can explicitly call hidden functions, e.g. c.A<B>::func(), so A<B> is not "the only possible caller" (if we ignore that both func are private).  It's true that A cannot know about (any possible) C, but the question only asks about B.

Comment: Or a more likely scenario: `A<B>* p = new C(); p->func();` -- this would call `A<B>::func` -- if of course it would compile.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, there's no need for dynamic dispatch because the type of `c` is known at compile time. The call to `B::func` will be hard coded.

If you were calling `func` through a `B*`, then you would be calling a virtual function. But in your highly contrived example, that would get you to `B::func` once again.

It doesn't make much sense to talk about dynamic dispatch from an `A*` since `A` is a template class - you can't make a generic `A`, only one that is bound to a particular subclass.

Comment: You can have an `A<B>*` though.

Answer (score 1):

> How could you implement class A such that if B has a virtual override, that it is dynamically dispatched, but statically dispatched if B doesn't?

As others have noticed, it's really hard to make sense of that question, but it made me remember something I have learned a long time ago, so here's a very long shot at answering your question:

```
template<typename Base> class A : private Base
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        std::count << "A::func";
    }
};
```

Given this, it depends on `A`'s base whether `func()` is virtual. If `Base` declares it `virtual` then it will be virtual in `A`, too. Otherwise it won't. See this:

```
class V
{
public:
    virtual void func() {}
};
class NV
{
};

class B : public A<V>  // makes func() virtual
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        std::count << "B::func";
    }
};

class C : public A<NV>  // makes func() non-virtual
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        std::count << "C::func";
    }
};
```

Would this happen to answer your question?

Comment: +1 for `template<typename Base> class A : private Base` which is... intriguing.  However, the fatal flaw I see here is that there's no suitable base class pointer type (`A<V>` is not convertible to `A<NV>`).  Given that it doesn't seem to really "hide" the virtualness in the way the question seemed to ask.

Comment: @Ben: Deriving from a template parameter is not all that uncommon for CRTP classes. I'm not sure what problem you point out regarding the base class conversions. And I already said that I don't know what the OP _really_ asked for.

Comment: @sbi: I woke up and made my question (and code) make a little more sense.

Comment: @sbi: Deriving from a template parameter is the opposite of CRTP, which takes the derived class as a template parameter.  (The former is still useful, even useful to combine with CRTP, but it's not CRTP.)

Comment: @Fred: I'm not aware of giving the impression that deriving from a template parameter _is_ CRTP.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the function is dynamically dispatched or not depends on two things:

a) whether the object expression is a reference or pointer type

b) whether the function (to which overload resolution resolves to) is virtual or not.

Coming to your code now:

```
  C c; 
  c.func();   // object expression is not of pointer/reference type. 
              // So static binding

  A <B> & ref = c; 
  ref.func(); // object expression is of reference type, but func is 
              // not virtual. So static binding


  A<D>* ptr = new D; 
  ptr->func(); // object expression is of pointer type, but func is not 
               // virtual. So static binding
```

So in short, 'func' is not dynamically dispatched.

Note that :: suppresses virtual function call mechanism.

> $10.3/12- "Explicit qualification with
>   the scope operator (5.1) suppresses
>   the virtual "call mechanism.

The code in OP2 gives error because the syntax X::Y can be used to invoke 'Y' in the scope of 'X' only if 'Y' is a static member in the scope of 'X'.

Comment: (a) is ambiguous: it could be misunderstood as references behaving differently than pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you just had to add a little trace and usage to answer your own question...

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct A { 
    void func() { 
        T::func(); 
    } 
}; 

struct B1 : A<B1> { 
    virtual void func() { 
        std::cout << "virtual void B1::func();\n";
    } 
}; 

struct B2 : A<B2> { 
    void func() { 
        std::cout << "void B2::func();\n";
    } 
}; 

struct C1 : B1 { }; 
struct C2 : B2 { }; 

struct C1a : B1 {
    virtual void func() {
        std::cout << "virtual void C1a::func();\n";
    }
};

struct C2a : B2 {
    virtual void func() {
        std::cout << "virtual void C2a::func();\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    C1 c1; 
    c1.func(); 

    C2 c2; 
    c2.func(); 

    B1* p_B1 = new C1a;
    p_B1->func();

    B2* p_B2 = new C2a;
    p_B2->func();
}
```

Output:

```
virtual void B1::func();
void B2::func();
virtual void C1a::func();
void B2::func();
```

Conclusion: A does take on the virtual-ness of B's func.

Comment: `A::func()` didn't even get used (and wouldn't compile if it were used).

Comment: The error message would be ` In member function ‘void A<T>::func() [with T = B1]’: error: cannot call member function ‘virtual void B1::func()’ without object`

Comment: @Ben: question was "How could you implement class A such that if B has a virtual override, that it is dynamically dispatched, but statically dispatched if B doesn't?".  Above shows virtual versus static dispatch depending on the member of B - A's version is hidden.  If you want to use A's version and not need one in B, then simply change A to something that can compile and remove func() from B2 - the concept holds.