# subclassing with or without virtuals vs performance vs convenience

Tags: c++, performance, inheritance, stl

It is well-known that STL classes do not use virtual methods anywhere (and STL does not use inheritance anywhere, too, and that these two facts are inter-related), and that STL is not unique in that.

Let's assume that other performance freaks exist on earth [well they exist], such performance freaks who ask themselves for every class  "do I need virtual methods for this class X ?" and "can this class X do without any virtuals, just like STL classes, for better performance ?"

Absense of any virtual methods (inclusing d'tor) makes polymorphism and subclassing more difficult than with "virtuals" base classes. Apparently "non-virtuals" classes are *not* well suited to be base classes.

Question: is there technique (for c++) that allows programmer to create *in one shot*  two versions of same class X, a "non-virtuals" version Xnv (for performance), and "virtuals" version Xv, for subclassing ? If this is not needed, please explain why.

`Post-note`

People answered
*"If you need subclassing, use virtuals. If you don't, don't use virtuals"*.

There is a problem with this suggestion. Couple of problems.

1) needs undergod changes changes over time. subclassing from class X was not needed then, but is needed now, or vice versa.
2) Person who writes the base class is not the same person who writes the derived class. This is clear from the question.   People have different thinking stypes, different judgements,  different needs. Clear, again.
3) Hence different programmers, answering question like "does inheriting from class X makes any sense?", will give different answers.  It is subjective, there is no cut-in-stone answer.
4) It contradicts what question asks.

Hence we want to satisfy two ends of the spectrum -- which happens often in engineering -- and  this is motivation behind the question.

The motivation was too complex to express concisely in the question. I assumed people can either (1) assume motivation exists as question was precisely formulated, or can (2) figure motivation because they already were in similar tradeoff-and-balance situation of c++ design.

Nobody figured the motivation -- to my surprise -- possibly even now. This shall be a lesson for me.

I accepted the answer that mentioned CRTP because it is hilarious pattern.

Comment: That technique is called JIT compiling. ;)

Comment: If you don't need virtuals, why add them? If you need them, you need them.

Comment: some STL classes do use virtual methods ...e.g. `std::streambuf`

Comment: @smerlin: There is some confusion and arguments around the *standard library* and the *STL*, where the *STL* is referred to the library originally implemented by Stepanov (containers, iterators, algorithms...). `std::streambuf` (as `std::iostream` and others) are part of the *standard library*, but not the *STL*

Comment: @David: Strictly speaking, in the context of the C++ language there is no such thing as the STL. To say some parts categorically belong in the STL and others don't seems to be unjustified from the start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual inheritance and static inheritance - mixing in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221163/virtual-inheritance-and-static-inheritance-mixing-in-c)

Comment: You can infact write classes to be both virtual and non-virtual. See my duplicate link. Also, virtual inheritance != virtual functions.

Comment: Contrary to your assertions, the STL does use virtual methods, and does use inheritance. And contrary to your main assumption, efficiency is not usually a consideration for making a method virtual or not. I'd say the question needs some rethinking.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: are you talking about those part of c++ std lib that are not stl ? nb stl != c++ std library

Comment: @Andrei: I meant the STL part of the C++ standard library. The original C++ STL spec from 1995 (Stepanov and Lee) didn't contain the word `virtual` at all. But that was before C++ exceptions were finalized. A `std::exception` has a virtual destructor, and various STL functions throw. And even the 1995 STL did use inheritance, for iterators and for functors. Cheers & hope this clarifies,

Comment: @David: I know, but since many people confuse those two, and think that STL is just a abbreviation for the C++ standard library, i assumed that this is the case for the OP aswell. Btw, especially for the STL by Stepanov, performance was a not so important design factor (e.g. see allocators or iterators).

Comment: @GMan: Stating that STL in the context of the C++ language does not exist... well, the STL is the library from which containers, iterators, algorithms and functors were borrowed and added to the C++ standard. In the standard they are never referred as STL, but the origin of them is that (non standard C++ library). If we are being picky I would go one step further and say that *in the context of the C++ standard* (rather than the *C++ language*) *there is no such thing as the STL*. Iterators did belong to the STL and streams or streambufs never did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: is there technique (for c++) that allows programmer to create in one shot two versions of same class X, a "non-virtuals" version Xnv (for performance), and "virtuals" version Xv, for subclassing ?

Why do that, when you can have your cake and eat it too?

With CRTP, you have compile-time polymorphism, and the ability for subclasses to override behavior, without any overhead for virtual functions.

Alternatively, you could use a "traits" class to inject behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could...

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void foo();
};

struct Dummy {};

template <bool is_virtual>
struct SelectBase
{
    typedef Base type;
};

template <>
struct SelectBase<false>
{
    typedef Dummy type;
};

template <bool is_virtual>
struct MyClass : SelectBase<is_virtual>::type
{
    ~MyClass();
    void foo();
};

int main()
{
    Base* xv = new MyClass<true>(); // virtual version
    MyClass<false>* xnv = new MyClass<false>(); // non-virtual version
    xv->foo(); // virtual call
    xnv->foo(); // non-virtual call
}
```

I can't really think of a good reason to do that though.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than worrying about performance first, a better question is "does inheriting from this class make a lick of sense?" If the answer is no, why make anything virtual? There are afterall some storage and performance advantages to what is essentially a final class. (While C++ does not supported the Java concept of a `final` class, a class with no virtual methods is pretty close to being 'final'.)

However, I typically go the opposite route: I tend to make the destructor virtual because someone else might see a use for inheriting from the class.

Comment: C++0x introduces the `final` contextual keyword for this reason.

Comment: Different poeple, when answering "does inheriting from class X will make any sense?", will give opposite answers, from yes to no to maybe, because their needs are different. Their needs are different. This is why I formulated this question -- to leave both possibilities open. This happens in engineering all the time -- trying to suit opposite ends of spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on the reasons that drive the decision of making a method virtual or not. Performance is **not** one reason to make your methods virtual or not, and as a matter of fact more often than not the effect of performance will be minimal <sup>[1]</sup>.

The decision on whether to provide virtual methods should be based on your requirements, in particular: do you need runtime polymorphism? If you do, then the methods should be virtual, if you don't then they should not.

<sup>[1]</sup> In a design with single inheritance, virtual dispatch takes only one extra indirection, while in multiple dispatch the cost is slightly higher, with potentially an extra pointer offset and indirection. The cost of that will be much smaller than any operation that the method does.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing is that you can simply write it later.

```
template<typename T> class something {
    virtual const T& operator*() = 0;
    virtual something<T>& operator++() = 0;  // This should be only prefix
    // etc
};

template<typename Derived, typename T> class something_better : public something<T> {
    typename Derived::const_iterator i;
public:
    something_better(const Derived& d) {
        i = d.begin();
    }
    const T& operator*() {
        return *i;
    }
    something<T>& operator++() {
        ++i;
        return *this;
    }
    something<T>& operator--() {
        --i;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Et voila- run-time polymorphic iteration. That was easy. As long as the iterator and container continue to be valid, of course.

If you want non-const iteration, and other things, then you'll need to wait until C++0x to deal with rvalues correctly. Or ask the `BOOST_FOREACH` people, they seem to have solved the problem somehow.

Comment: Here's how Boost.ForEach handles the situation: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

I take issue with this assumption:

> just like STL classes, for better performance ?

I disagree that the lack of virtual is for performance reasons.

> Absense of any virtual methods (inclusing d'tor) makes polymorphism and subclassing more difficult than with "virtuals" base classes.

Very true. And this would be my reason for not having virtual functions in the container classes. It is deliberately designed not to be sub-classed. It is better to use membership rather than inheritance when using the container classes.

> Question: is there technique (for c++) that allows programmer to create in one shot two versions of same class X, a "non-virtuals" version Xnv (for performance), and "virtuals" version Xv, for subclassing ? If this is not needed, please explain why.

Why would you want to do that.
If you are designing for performance your interface usually changes from the basic OO interface. You tend to become a little more lax in exposing your internals (as the trade is usually trading speed for tighter coupling of your classes).

To get more performance the algorithm usually knows more about the internals so that it can use this information to make assumptions about how it works. Thus you can get performance increases at the cost of coupling your storage to the algorithms that are using the storage.

Comment: Re "I disagree that the lack of virtual is for performance reasons." Virtual overhead can be quite significant. For example, see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.115.578&rep=rep1&type=pdf . The STL containers are highly optimized code, and getting rid of that virtual overhead was one of the things the designers of the STL addressed right from the start.

Comment: @David: Though there can be performance implications with virtual functions I disagree this was a major consideration when developing the STL (though I am sure it was **A** consideration). I doubt the paper you quote had **any** influence as it seems to be published after 1996 while the STL was originally freely available in 1994.

Comment: @David: Both Stepanov and Musser were doing research into generic programming and how it could benefit development. Thus it was more of the generic usability of the code that was the focus of their research. But like everything performance will always be taken into consideration, I just object to thinking that it is the major consideration.

Comment: Stepanov, not being an OOP aficionado, would not have deigned to make the STL something from which a programmer can inherit. However, the C++ committee (WG21) made significant changes to the STL as developed by Stepanov & Musser. That containers have a non-virtual dtor is thanks to WG21, not Stepanov & Musser. C++11 continues this tradition. If not for performance reasons, why?

Comment: @David: If not for performance reasons, why? As stated above. Extension from membership not inheritance is better design.